# IIS Url rewrite module 2 DB provider with using RegEx

Tags: .net, regex, mod-rewrite, iis, url-rewrite-module

i googled this, but i can't found any information about my question...

I use IIS 8 and URL rewrite module (DB provider). So when i have this rule in database
originalUrl - `old/qwerty/test1` redirect to newURL - `new/qwerty/test2` this works fine. Server redirect me to newURL, but can i use in database URLs with RegEx? something like this `old/qwerty/(*)` ??

**How i can use rules with RegEx in DB provider in URL rewrite module ??**

This is my sample rules in web.config file

```
<rules>
    <rule name="DbProviderTest" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{DB_Redirect:{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Comment: What does the config look like with the redirect that you hardcoded to work?

Comment: I don't have rules in config file. Redirect urls exists in my database.

You can see this [link](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module) - example of DB provider